# ajax toolkit : Javascript alert not displaying any value

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is OnClick Javascript code invoked from a List Button on a related list UI.

```
var cid = '{!Case.Id}';
    varQueryString = "select id,integration_status__c,Target_System__c from transaction__c where case__c ="+"\'"+cid+"\'";
    varQueryResult = sforce.connection.query(varQueryString);
    if(varQueryResult.size == 0)
    {
    alert('No Transaction Available to perform Validation');
    }
    if(varQueryResult.size > 1)
    {
    alert('More Than one Transactions are present. Please delete one of the transaction');
    }
    if(varQueryResult.size == 1)
    {

    alert('Invoking Validate Transaction');
    var recs = varQueryResult.getArray("records");
    alert(recs[0]); //LINE 1
    var tid = recs[0].id; //LINE 2
    alert(recs[0].id); // LINE 3
```

I am getting no output (a blank alert box to be more precise) at Line 3 but Line 1 displays a pop up box with the data elements.

Line 1 output :

> {type:'Transaction__c', Id:'a3P11000000Ekc9EAC',
>   Integration_Status__c:'Processing', Target_System__c:null, }

Line 3 : Blank alert pop up box..why ?

Can someone let me know why ?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Try `alert(recs[0].Id)`. Though I would have expected the alert to display "undefined" if that was the problem.

Comment: Resolved my issue..How silly of me..tx keith :)

Comment: OK. I've posted that as an answer too so you can accept it using the tick to show the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Try `alert(recs[0].Id)`. Though I would have expected the alert to display "undefined" if that was the problem.